# Tensorflow does not get GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

Python verion: 3.7.6

Tensorflow version: 2.3.0

CUDA: 10.2.89

CUDNN: 10.2

nvcc --version:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:32:27_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

nvidia-smi output:

```
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | NVIDIA-SMI 451.48       Driver Version: 451.48       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
    |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
    | GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
    | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
    |===============================+======================+======================|
    |   0  GeForce GTX 1080   WDDM  | 00000000:04:00.0  On |                  N/A |
    |  0%   47C    P8     8W / 200W |    463MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
    +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Processes:                                                                  |
    |  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
    |        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
    |=============================================================================|
    |    0   N/A  N/A      1268    C+G   Insufficient Permissions        N/A      |
    |    0   N/A  N/A      1308    C+G   Insufficient Permissions        N/A      |
    |    0   N/A  N/A      4936    C+G   ...\Direct4\jabra-direct.exe    N/A      |
    |    0   N/A  N/A      7500    C+G   Insufficient Permissions        N/A      |
    |    0   N/A  N/A      7516    C+G   ...w5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe    N/A      |
    |    0   N/A  N/A      9668    C+G   Insufficient Permissions        N/A      |
    |    0   N/A  N/A     10676    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe         N/A      |
    |    0   N/A  N/A     10828    C+G   ...st\Desktop\Mattermost.exe    N/A      |
    |    0   N/A  N/A     11536    C+G   ...8bbwe\Microsoft.Notes.exe    N/A      |
    |    0   N/A  N/A     14604    C+G   ...es.TextInput.InputApp.exe    N/A      |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried:

```
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

Num GPUs Available: 0
```

Why tensorflow is not able to detect the GPU?

Comment: Can you add logs that you get after import tensorflow and along with that provide system information.

Comment: Yes, please add the logs, without that there is not much we can do to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use the TensorFlow-GPU version and you have downloaded unsupported versions.

**Note: GPU support is available for Ubuntu and Windows with CUDA enabled cards only.**

If you have a Cuda enabled card follow the instructions provided below.

As stated in Tensorflow documentation. The software requirements are as follows.

```
Nvidia gpu drivers - 418.x or higher
Cuda - 10.1 (TensorFlow >= 2.1.0)
cuDNN - 7.6
```

Make sure you have these exact versions of the software mentioned above. See [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements)

Also, check the system requirements [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements).

Make sure you have installed all the c++ redistributables - [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

For downloading the software mentioned above see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#linux_setup).

For downloading TensorFlow follow the instructions provided [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#1.-install-the-python-development-environment-on-your-system) to correctly install the necessary packages.